# wordpress can't update homepage

Tags: wordpress

I encountered a very strange problem. That is the homepage cannot be updated. I modified some pictures on the homepage in the dashboard, and updated it, it did not change.

But when I publish articles and products or modify other pages, it can be displayed normally. Only the homepage cannot be updated.

At first I thought it was a cdn error, so I cleared the cache and refreshed it, but it didn't work.

Then I deleted the cache of the plugin "wp super cache", but it didn't work.

Finally, so I tried to use another page as the home page. It is still the original page without any changes, it seems to be fixed.

I download website resources from the server and run other domain names locally. All the changes I made are displayed normally.

debug have no info,and can preview my change are effective, but page can't work.

This is very strange, please help, thank you very much.

Comment: Please share site URL also can you please check it using debug mode on may be it will give you any hint ?

Comment: Did you checked whether the page content is hardcoded in the theme ? Where you able to `Preview` the page after making the changes?

Comment: @Sanket Thakkar No bug.Sorry, Link cannot be provided to you, what do you want to know, I can tell you

Comment: @Akhilesh B Chandran what do you mean? Usually update directly, you can see the changed place，and i try preview,It was success,my change are effective.

Comment: @YJYan what am asking is, whether you are able to see the changes in HOME page when you PREVIEW the page (using preview button), after making your edits? I mean before the PUBLISH.

Comment: @Akhilesh B Chandran Yes,I can preview it and my change are effective,but homepage still can't work

Comment: @YJYan did you checked whether you are editing the correct HOME page? Say you have a duplicate of it and you are editing that duplicate page? And later when the HOME page is accessed, you are seeing the original unedited HOME page?

Second guess is, do you have Cloudfare enabled? If so, flush the cache.

Comment: @Akhilesh B Chandran No,it is not duplicate page,and not cloudflare problem.But thank you!

Comment: @YJYan am sorry. I ran out of suggestions. Maybe hiring a developer will help you resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved, and it turns out that it is still a caching problem. If you still encounter this problem, please check the cache first.

Thank you